# Method to find current location without using google map api

Tags: codeigniter, currentlocation

Google map api's current location is not working in some environments.Is there any other service we can use to get the current Geo-location

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html5 for this.

See example below:

JS)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showLocation(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  alert("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude);
}

function errorHandler(err) {
  if(err.code == 1) {
    alert("Error: Access is denied!");
  }else if( err.code == 2) {
    alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
  }
}
function getLocation(){

   if(navigator.geolocation){
      // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
      var options = {timeout:60000};
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, 
                                               errorHandler,
                                               options);
   }else{
      alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
   }
}
</script>
```

HTML button to call function

```
   <form>
     <input type="button" onclick="getLocation();" value="Get Location"/>
   </form>
```